# Use Variable Which is in main method in Another Method

Tags: java, variables, methods

I'm trying to create a simple program to output the number of stars entered by user. I'm trying to learn how to use more than one method to do this
Here's my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Alpha 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         int n;

        System.out.println("Enter no. of stars");
        n = input.nextInt();

    }
    public static void Loop ()
    {
        for (int counter = 1; counter <= n; counter++)
        {
            System.out.println("*");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that in the Loop method, I am unable to use the variable n
Is there a way to use a variable which is in the main method, in another one?
Ty

-Pingu

Comment: Pass it as a parameter... See my code below...

Comment: The Q&A format of this web site is unsuitable for teaching this kind of conceptual basics. To properly explain how to do this would amount to a tutorial on what an argument is and what a method is.

Comment: This might be helpful https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a basic programming thing taught in any tutorial, book or site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Alpha 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     int n;

    System.out.println("Enter no. of stars");
    n = input.nextInt();

    Loop(n); //calls Loop function and passes parameter n
}
public static void Loop(int n)  //this function now expects a number n
{
    for (int counter = 1; counter <= n; counter++)
    {
        System.out.println("*");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, those comments made me understand how to pass parameters

Comment: If you consider this to be the answer to your question, it would be great if you could mark it as the answer (green tick under the vote buttons). Thanks! @IPing7

Answer (score 2):

simply pass it as parameter:

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         int n;

        System.out.println("Enter no. of stars");
        n = input.nextInt();
        Loop(n);

    }
    public static void Loop (int count)
    {
        for (int counter = 1; counter <= count; counter++)
        {
            System.out.println("*");
        }
    }
```

Comment: One thing I didn't get, since you say Loop(n), shouldn't it also be
public static void Loop (int n) ?

Comment: you can make it private but you have to keep it static. otherwise you would get: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method Loop(int) from the type Alpha" because you main method is also static.

Answer (score 2):

Pass it as a paramteer

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Alpha 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         int n;    
        System.out.println("Enter no. of stars");
        n = input.nextInt();    
        loop(n); // added this

    }
    public static void loop (int n) // changed here
    {
        for (int counter = 1; counter <= n; counter++)
        {
            System.out.println("*");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that review

Comment: btw I think loop is a better naming for methods then Loop.

Comment: True, @StefanBeike, names that start with a capital letter should be used to declare classes, methods should start with a non-capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use it as a instance variable and for better understanding name your class like `StarClass` it can provide better understanding. Good programming practice.

But you should avoid unneccesserily making instance variable without any logic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I also think you could declare n as a public variable.
That should make it accessible throughout the code.

public int n;

But I guess that passing it as parameter is a better practice, since you don't create a deppendance inside your code. What I mean is, if something changes with the variable you break the function. It's good practice to always keep things "modular" in your code, so it makes it more resilient to changes and debugging.
It's better if you get used to it from the beggining =)

Comment: you're talking about a `static` field then. The access modifier does nothing within the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways.. one has been posted already as answer and the other one would be using the variable as a field. This way you can access (and modify) it in every method without having to pass it on.

```
public class Alpha 
{

    static int n;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter no. of stars");
        n = input.nextInt();
        loop();
    }
    public static void loop ()
    {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < n; counter++)
        {
            System.out.println("*");
        }
    }
}
```

And please start method names with lowercase and counting with 0. It's common practise and it helps a lot to use the standards right from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Like this you can use variable from different methods in different methods

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int sum=0;
    int a=Sum(sum);
    System.out.println("The Average of the numbers is: "+a);
    
}

public static int Sum(int sum) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the total count of number for Average: ");
    int a=sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=1;i<=a;i++) {
        
        System.out.println("Enter the"+i+"Number: ");
        int b=sc.nextInt();
        sum+=b;
    }
    int avg=sum/a;
    return avg;
}
```