# How to transfer a user enterd variable value to another method

Tags: java, variables, methods

Ok so a user types in an value for a variable named email in a signup process, then another method is called for them to sign in.  When they sign in they have to use the same email they signed up with. Heres my code:

```
public static void signup() {
  String email;

  System.out.println("Please type in an email");
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  email = input.nextLine();
   signin();
}

 public static void signin() {
   String emailForSignin;

   System.out.println("Please sign in with your email");
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   emailForSignIn = input.nextLine();
   if (emailForSignin != email) {
     System.out.print("Thats not right, try again")
 }
}
```

Now im not sure how to transfer the variable "email" to the signin method,  can anybody tell me how to do that? Thanks

EDIT: Tried useing

```
    public static void signin(String email) {
}
```

and got the error:

Error: The method signin(java.lang.String) in the type signup is not applicable for the arguments

Comment: Do you know what method parameters and arguments are?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Variables between methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499785/passing-variables-between-methods)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854137/how-can-we-pass-variables-from-one-method-to-another-in-the-same-class-without-t

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614365/passing-a-string-from-one-method-to-another-method

Comment: Or even https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610174/use-variable-which-is-in-main-method-in-another-method

Comment: Also, once you fix that, you'll need to deal with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: And don't create multiple `Scanner` objects. Create one and use it everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a method parameter but not passing it in. When you call the method signin(String email), you need to give it a string that will then be recognized as the variable email.

Try this when calling the method:

```
signin(email);
```

Also nitpicking thing but will greatly improve the readability of your code, subsequent words in method names should be capitalized, like this:

```
signIn(email);
```